# Python Regex: Apostrophes only when placed within letters, not as quotation marks

Tags: python, regex

define each word to be the longest contiguous sequence of alphabetic characters (or just letters), including up to one apostrophe if that apostrophe is sandwiched between two letters.

```
[a-z]+[a-z/'?a-z]*[a-z$]
```

It doesn't match the letter 'a'.

Comment: Do you have sample data with expected return? Do you only allow lower case letters too?

Comment: I think you're looking for `[a-z]+[a-z/'?a-z]*([a-z]|$)`? In your snippet, the `$` in brackets was interpreted as matching a literal `$` character.

Comment: By the way, check out https://regexr.com/ for regex testing and debugging.

Comment: Thanks. I use pythex.org all the time. Yes, string is already in lowercase. 
Unfortunately, [a-z]+[a-z/'?a-z]*([a-z]|$) does not work, as it does not match the single-letter word 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
[a-zA-Z]*(?:[a-zA-Z]\'[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]*
```

Match 0 or more letters `[a-zA-Z]*?` followed by either an apostrophe surrounded by 2 letters **or** a single letter `(?:[a-zA-Z]\'[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z])` then match 0 or more letters `[a-zA-Z]*`

For just lowercase letters

```
[a-z]*(?:[a-z]\'[a-z]|[a-z])[a-z]*
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when using the testing / debugging site pythex.org, it shows that with the program you've constructed, it does not match the apostrophe in the word "I'm".

Comment: @user12916679 Updated the answer to handle lower and upper case letters

Comment: Thanks, the input is a string with lowercase letters. Appreciate it, though.

Comment: @user12916679 After some playing around I think I have it working

Comment: @user12916679 for just lower case letters it's a bit shorter `[a-z]*(?:[a-z]\'[a-z]|[a-z])[a-z]*`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
^(?:[a-z]+|[a-z]+'[a-z]+)$
```

with `re.IGNORECASE`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/lXnqW0/1)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the character class notation. The stuff between `[` and `]` is a list of characters to match. It does not make sense to list the same character multiple times, and basically all characters except `]` and `-` (and initial `^` for negation) simply match themselves, i.e. lose their regex special meaning.

Lets's rephrase your requirement. You want an alphabetic `[a-z]` repeated one or more times `+`, optionally followed by an apostrophe and another sequence of alphabetics.

```
[a-z]+('[a-z]+)?
```

In some regex dialects, you might prefer the non-capturing opening parenthesis `(?:` instead of plain `(`.